# why jsvc is occupying more memory in the server?

Tags: solr

I am working on poolparty which is a metadata api. In poolparty, I am using 2 servers for PROD. In one of my server jsvc64 is occupying 70% of the total memory and in other only 20% of the total. Can you please tell reasons why it is occupying more memory in one server.

Answer (score 0):

Only one server is serving more number of requests. 
The tomcat process does not release memory that has been consumed at one point in time by the application.

So this indicates that one server at one time has used 70% of memory.